# Replace contiguous line feeds or new line characters with a single newline in Flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex, flex4

I need to replace multiple contiguous new line/line feed characters in flex with a single new line character.

Example:

The string

```
"My name is blah blah \n\n\n\n
My name is blah \r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

Should be converted to

```
"My name is blah blah \n
My name is blah \n"
```

Hope the example makes it easier to understand.

I am using a  component to render it.

I guess using regex would be the easiest way to do this, but still it would be great if people can point me out to references/examples to get this done with ease.

I am using flex 4.5.

Thanks,

Neeraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.replace` method to do the job, it's possible to use both string or regular expressions to match some part of a string value. So regarding to your question the code will look like below:

```
var filter: String = "My name is blah\r\r\r blah \n\n\n\r\nMy name is blah\r\n\r\r\n\n\n\r\n";

filter = filter.replace(/(\r|\n)+/g, "\n");
```

Comment: +1, but please change `(\r|\n)` to `[\r\n]`.  It's more readable that way, and potentially *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> multiple contiguous new line/line feed characters

If you mean sequence "\r\n" then:

```
var myString:String = "text\r\ntext\r\ntext\r\n";
myString = myString.split("\r").join("\n").split("\n\n").join("\n");
```

Comment: Hi I have added an example for illustration.

Comment: Kind of roundabout approach, but it might work.  But first you need to change all those forward-slashes (`/`) to backslashes (`\\`).

Comment: >But first you need to change all those forward-slashes
Yes. You are right :)